# Override admin js file not working on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides

I tried to override `magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/date.js`

For this,  I have created a custom module with the following:

**view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js** with the following content

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date": "namespace/module/js/form/element/date",

        }
    }
}
```

and in this path `namespace/module/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/date.js` I have my js.

After deploy,  I receive an error in the  console, that my js is **not found** in pub/....date.js

Why this is not created? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi I am also trying to override js file which is in the base. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date": "namespace/module/js/form/element/date",

        }
    }
}
```

to path => `view/base/requirejs-config.js`

```
 var config = {
        "map": {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date": "namespace_module/js/form/element/date",
"Magento_Ui/js/form/client": "namespace_module/js/form/client"

            }
        }
    }
```

after changing the code try to re run `setup:upgrade` & `setup:static-content:deploy` command

Comment: and the path for the js file are ok?

Comment: i tried and is not working

Comment: @AlinLupoiu which area you are looking for?

Comment: i am looking for ths file base/web/js/form/element/date.js, so is in base. now my files are generated in pub but i still receive other error

Comment: namespace/module/js/form/date.js net::ERR_ABORTED required.js 1895

Comment: @AlinLupoiu change `namespace/module` to `namespace_module` see my answer.

Comment: i did this and now i have another err : /en_US/namespace/js/form/element/abstract.js net::ERR_ABORTED required.js:1895 even i don't have any abastract.js file in this folder

Comment: @AlinLupoiu copy the `abstract.js` file from core and paste the same location in your module i.e `view/base/web/js/form/element/`. and try to re run commands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66534/discussion-between-alin-lupoiu-and-magento-two).

Comment: @AlinLupoiu are you working `git repository` based modules/projects?

Comment: yes i use git  repository

Comment: @AlinLupoiu I don't know how to work using  `git repository`. So is there any source to learn?